# In Graphviz, how to layout subgraphs in different orientations?

Tags: graphviz, dot

There is *rankdir* for the global graph which sets the orientation of the layout. What about subgraph or cluster - is there a way to have one subgraph in TD layout and another subgraph in BT?

How to achieve the graph in the attached image with following (incorrect) code?

```
digraph G {
  subgraph cluster0 {
     rankdir="TD";  
      A; B;
      A -> B;
  }
  subgraph cluster1 {
    rankdir="BT"; // this doesn't produce the desired output 
      C; D;
      D -> C;
  }
}
```

[image: hypothetical output from Graphviz]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, rankdir is only allowed at top level (graph)

but in simple cases you can work around it by

to go in opposite direction:

```
C->D[dir=back]
```

to go in to the side:

```
{rank=same C D}
```